# probability - number of const points in permutation

Tags: probability, permutations

$\pi$ - random permutation.
1. Compute expected value of const points of $\pi$
2. Compute Variety.
3. Estimate the probability that $\pi$ has more than $n/2$ const points

Firstly, I have a problem with 1.

Look,
Let $!n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$ means number of disorders.
So $$EX = \sum_{i=1}^{n}i\frac{{n\choose i}(!(n-i))^n}{n!}$$.
But I can't find compact formula, not to mention the variance...

Comment: We are looking at the permutations of $1,2,\dots,n$. Let $X_i=1$ if $i$ is left fixed, and $0$ otherwise. Then the number of fixed points is $X_1+\cdots+X_n$. By the linearity of expectation this is $E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_n)$. Easily $E(X_i)=1/n$, so our expectation is $n(1/n)$.

Comment: The variance is more complicated, same basic method.  Undoubtedly it is somewhere on MSE, and I probably gave an answer for the variance once or twice.

Comment: What does mean " left fixed" ?

Comment: Here it means $i$ stays fixed, is not moved elsewhere by $\pi$, thus $\pi(i) = i$.

Comment: Ok, Expected value is simple :) I wrongly thought about it - we have FIXED permutation (one of $n!$). Give me a moment, I'll think about variance     So expected value = 1 ?

Comment: The expected number of fixed points (you called them constant points) is $1$.  The permutation is not fixed, it is randomly chosen, with all permutations equally likely.

Comment: Hmm, check my, please : $$Var(X) = E((X_1+...+X_n)^2) - (EX)^2 = EX_1 + ... + EX_n + E(X_iX_j)_{i\neq j} - 1 = E(X_iX_j)_{i\neq j}$$       $X_iX_j = 1$ if and only if $X_i = 1 $ and $X_j = 1$ Because of independence $E(X_iX_j) = \frac{1}{n^2}$. Finally, $$Var(X) = \frac{2}{n}$$

Comment: The basic technique is right, but we do not have independence. We have $X_iX_j=1$ iff $X_i=1$ and $X_j=1$. If $X_i=1$ then $\Pr(X_j=1)=\frac{1}{n-1}$. Thus $E(X_iX_j)=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ if $i\ne j$.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. $VarX (n)(n-1)\frac{1}{n(n-1)} 1 = EX$   Tomorrow I'll try 3.

Comment: Hey, could you look at below post ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I'll try estmiate probablity that $\pi$
Look at Chebyshev's inequality:
$$Pr(|X-EX| \ge c\sigma) \le \frac{1}{c^2} $$
$$Pr(|X-1|)\ge c) \le \frac{1}{c^2}$$
Let's assume that $X\ge 1$.
$$Pr(|X-1|)\ge c) = Pr(X-1\ge c) = Pr(X > c) \le \frac{1}{c^2}$$
Let $c = n/2$, then
$$Pr(X > n/2) \le \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Ok ? I don't know Can I get $c=n/2$

Second method:
I estimate number of permutations that have more than $n/2$ fixed points.
$$\sum_{i=n/2 +1}^{n} {n\choose i}!(n-i) =\sum_{i=n/2 +1}^{n} {n\choose i}\sum_{i=0}^{n-i}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!} \le \sum_{i=n/2+1}^{n}{n\choose i}\sum_{i=0}^{n-i}\frac{1^i}{i!} \le e\sum_{i=n/2+1}^{n}{n\choose i} \le e\sum_{i=0}^{n/2+1}{n\choose i}  $$
What is probablity that we get such permutation that it has more than $n/2$ fixed points  ? It is lower than $$e\sum_{i=0}^{n/2+1}{n\choose i} \frac{1}{n!} = e\sum_{i=0}^{n/2+1} \frac{1}{(n-i)!i!} \le 
\frac{e}{n!n!} = O(\frac{1}{n!n!} $$
So this probablity very fast decreases. (fastert than any polymonial)