# Matching 12 answers to 12 questions: it's not luck!

Tags: probability

I have 12 questions and 12 answers on a test. Each answer can only be matched to 1 question. 
I have only one attempt to answer.
What number of correct answers can be considered better (statistically significant - P<0,01) than a random choice and why? How to prove it's not luck, just having one try? 
Thank you.

Comment: Hint:  see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108434/probability-number-of-const-points-in-permutation)

Comment: If we assign randomly and $X$ is the number of correct answers, then we have $E(X)=Var(X)=1$. So, assuming a normal distributed variable is at least a reasonable approximation. For a rigorous calculation, you need the probabilities for $0,1,2,\cdots ,10,12$ correct answers. Moreover, you have to specify the significance-level.

Comment: Thanks Peter. What if p-values < 0,01?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with a python script.

```
from math import factorial

def derangements(n):
    f = factorial(n)
    return sum((-1)**k*f//factorial(k) for k in range(n+1))

def choose(n,m):
    if m > n:
        return 0
    return factorial(n)//(factorial(m)*factorial(n-m))

d = [choose(12,k)*derangements(12-k) for k in range(13)]
assert sum(d) ==factorial(12)
for k in range(13):
    print(k, sum(d[k:])/factorial(12))
```

which produced the output

```
0 1.0
1 0.6321205586787184
2 0.2642411194451125
3 0.08030138730225536
4 0.018988189183501685
5 0.0036597748316498317
6 0.0005942986411736411
7 8.31103695687029e-05
8 1.0359046817380151e-05
9 1.0584515792849126e-06
10 1.3987427181871627e-07
11 2.08767569878681e-09
12 2.08767569878681e-09
```

This means, for example,  that the probability of getting $4$ or more correct by pure chance is about $1.9\%$, so if the $p$-value is $1\%$, the answer to your question is $5$.

I think the script is self-explanatory, but please ask if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you very much. My output is different, I'll check. Anyway, I'm more interested in the second part of the answer. Any number of correct answers that has a probability of occurring less than 0.01 is statistically significant. Correct? I too have reasoned the same way. But, how to prove it's not luck, just having one try?

Comment: @user2450750 Maybe we computed different things.  My values are not for the probability of $k$ correct answer but for **at least** $k$ correct answers.  I took the question to mean that the result is statistically significant if the probability of getting at least that number of correct answers is $<1\%$, but I can't say what the "official" interpretation would be, or even if there is one.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This explains the different output.